# How to cast a Promise<Response>?

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I use `fetch` to query some JSON data from an API.

The helper function I wrote returns a `Promise<Response>` (this is a simplified version)

```
const apiCall = (): Promise<Response> => fetch('http://the.api.com').then(r => r.json())
```

I then use it like this:

```
export class Case {
  Uuid?:       string
  Topic?:      string
  public constructor(init?:Partial<Case>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
}

callApi()
  .then(r => allCases.value = r.Data as Array<Case>) // the error is on this line
  .catch(() => {{}})
```

**My problem**: TypeScript reports an error:

```
TS2339: Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

The program goes through successfully anyway, but I would like to understand this error and fix it (mostly to better understand TS in general).

I then tried to hint `r` with the expected type:

```
interface ApiResponse {
  Data: Array<Case>
}

callApi('/case', 'GET')
  .then((r: ApiResponse) => allCases.value = r.Data as Array<Case>)
  .catch(() => {{}})
```

This brings in two errors now:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(r: ApiResponse) =&gt; Case[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) =&gt; Case[] | PromiseLike&lt;Case[]&gt;'.
Types of parameters 'r' and 'value' are incompatible.
Property 'Data' is missing in type 'Response' but required in type 'ApiResponse'.

ESLint: This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression. (@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion)
```

**How can I express the fact that what comes from my helper function should be treated as an Object (with a `Data` key)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `callApi` as follows:

```
const callApi = (): Promise<ApiResponse> => fetch('http://the.api.com').then(r => r.json())
```

Looking at the [type definitions of node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/%40types/index.d.ts) tells me:

- Return type of `fetch` is `Promise<Response>`
- Return type of `Response.json` is `Promise<unknown>`

So the return type of your `callApi` function is `Promise<unknown>` and not `Promise<Response>`.

Then this should work:

```
callApi().then(r => allCases.value = r.Data).catch(() => {{}})
```

Why this solution of yours doesn't work:

```
callApi('/case', 'GET')
    .then((r: ApiResponse) => allCases.value = r.Data as Array<Case>)
    .catch(() => {{}})
```

Here you are passing a wrongly-types callback function as an argument to `then` since the type of `r` is not `ApiResponse` but `Response` as you have typed it before. This results in a TS error.